# Inserting a date range into SQL Server using ASP.NET c#

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, date, range

I am developing a web application which will allow users to enter a start date and an end date. As I would like this to show up later in a calendar, I believe I need to insert every date between the start date and end date into the database table. For example:
    01/01/2012
    02/01/2012
    03/01/2012
    04/01/2012

Is there an easy way of doing this when I have just the start date and end date, e.g. 01/01/2012 and 04/01/2012?

Thanks

Comment: Use a stored procedure which takes the start and end date, or since you're already running asp.net, just call INSERT from a loop.

Comment: Please use unambiguous date formats (e.g. `YYYYMMDD`). It's not immediately obvious what country you're in and therefore whether `04/01/2012` is April 1st or January 4th. You can tell by reading a bit more, but why make that hard?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than a loop, you could try:

```
;WITH x(n) AS
(
  SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @EndDate) + 1) 
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id]) - 1
   FROM sys.all_objects
)
-- INSERT dbo.table_name(date_column)
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, n, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, '19000101', @StartDate), '19000101'))
FROM x;
```

(Comment out the `INSERT` when you trust the logic and the output.)

Also if 2000+ days is not a large enough swing, you could change to `sys.all_columns` (7500+) or use your own numbers table.

Answer (score 0):

I question the need to do this based on your stated requirements, however, this is how:

```
DECLARE @InsertDate DATETIME = @StartDate;
WHILE @InsertDate <= @EndDate
BEGIN
    INSERT dbo.MyTable (Date) VALUES (@InsertDate)
    SET @InsertDate = @InsertDate + 1 --SQL does implicit conversion from integer to date (1 = 1 day)
END
```

**EDIT**: to address comment, this is also valid (possibly recommended, though I've never had an issue with the implicit conversion *when used with DATETIME*)

```
    SET @InsertDate = dateadd(d, 1, @InsertDate)
```

Comment: I recommend against the implicit shorthand. This doesn't work with `DATE`, for example. Just type `DATEADD`, it's much safer and it doesn't change your billable hours.

Comment: You've never had an issue with the implicit conversion because you haven't tried it with `DATE`, or `DATETIME2`, or `TIME`, or `DATETIMEOFFSET`.